# how can I implement the cast to chromecast using the dailymotion api

Tags: ios, dailymotion-api

I'm wondering how I could implement the cast to `chromecast` using `Dailymotion` api , because I need to send a media item to `chromecast` to reproduce when with the dailymotion I only know the ID of the video

Answer (score 0):

The chromecast feature is not accessible threw the API.
You can get your video url using this endpoint: 
`https://api.dailymotion.com/video/{id}?fields=url`then you have to manage the Chromecast part in your app.

But if you embed the player in your app, you can send the video to Chromecast using this button:[image]